# javascript design pattern: how to create sub-module and access parent module private vars and functions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module-pattern

I have the following:

```
mod.a = (function() {
    var myPrivateVar = 'a';
    function myPrivateFct() {
        //do something I will need in my sub-module (mod.a.b)
    }
    return {
        //some public functions
    }
})();

mod.a.b = (function() {
    // some local vars and functions

    return {
          mySubModuleFct:function() {
              // here I want to call mod.a.myPrivateFct();
          }
})();
```

I want to create a sub-module and call a private function from my parent module mod.a. How can I do this while following the best practices of the module pattern?

Answer (score 2):

A coworker showed me how to do it. It's actually very elegant.

```
mod.a = (function() {
    var myPrivateVar = 'a';
    function myPrivateFct() {
        //do something I will need in my sub-module (mod.a.b)
    }
    return {
        b: {
            bPublicMethod:function() {
                myPrivateFct(); // this will work!
            }
        }
        //some public functions
    }
})();

//call like this
mod.a.b.bPublicMethod(); // will call a.myPrivateFct();
```

Comment: ah yeah good, also if you havent read this check it out http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/, explains what your coworker showed you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using **John Resig's Simple Inheritance** code for more object-oriented approach to javascript:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

It allows you to write this:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  }
});
var Ninja = Person.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super( false );
  }
});

var p = new Person(true);
p.dancing; // => true

var n = new Ninja();
n.dancing; // => false
```

Comment: That might work, but it is not really what I am looking for. I know that I could use inheritance the way you specified it, but I would need to re-write the current module that I have. I also want to follow the module pattern.

Anyone?

Comment: ah, you use `Class`. According to MDN IE doesn't support it

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira that's why the blog post I linked to contains the implementation of Class so you don't have to rely on browser providing it.

Comment: @JakubKonecki ah ok, I see now! Thank you